# Pass input to Popen process

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I cannot find a proper solution for the following case. So, basically I want to pipe two shell commands, and pass some input data (`mypassword` here) to the 2nd one. Here's some code demonstrating the problem:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

args1 = shlex.split("find /home/vasya/rmps/ -name *.rpm")
ps = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

args2 = shlex.split("xargs rpmsign --addsign")
p2 = subprocess.Popen(args2, stdin=ps.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps.stdout.close()
output = p2.communicate('mypassword\n')[0]
print(output)
```

When run it asks in the console: `Enter pass phrase:` and stops despite the fact that I am passing the pass phrase already (my `mypassword` input).

Where is my fault and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stdin to `xargs` is the output of `find`, you can't *also* input something else.

One option would be to write the result of `find` to a file and use the `-a` (`--arg-file`) option of xargs.  This would allow you to input filenames while still keeping `stdin` free to be piped in from your python program (via `communicate`)